# How to modify a Java bytecode using ASM 4.0

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I am new to ASM framework. I have been working around this ASM framework for a week. I saw tutorials in net regarding parsing a class and Generating a .class file from scratch.
But am unable to follow how to modify a existing class in ASM.

I am unable to follow the flow of execution between the `ClassVisitor`, `ClassWriter` and `ClassReader`.

Kindly solve my issue by giving me a ASM example for the following code.

```
public class ClassName {
  public void showOne() {
    System.out.println("Show One Method");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassName c = new ClassName();
    c.showOne();
  }
}
```

The above class should be modified as:

```
public class ClassName {
  public void showOne() {
    System.out.println("Show One Method");
  }

  public void showTwo() { // <- Newly added method
    System.out.println("Show Two Method");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassName c = new ClassName();
    c.showOne();
    c.showTwo(); // <- Newly inserted method call
  }
}
```

What should be the ASM code to modify it?

I used the ASMifier tool to generate the code. But I don't know where to apply it.

Comment: @MartinFrank but i want to create a new mwthod and call it. the one specified there was at a basic level!

Comment: Np. Happens for me also.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your requirements are a bit underspecified. Below is an example program which uses ASM’s visitor API for transforming a class assumed to have the structure of your question to the resulting class. I added a convenience method taking a byte array and returning a byte array. Such a method can be used in both cases, a static transformation applied to class files on disk as well as in an Instrumentation agent.

When combining a `ClassWriter` with a `ClassVisitor` passed to a `ClassReader` as below, it will automatically replicate every feature of the source class so you have to override only these methods where you want to apply changes.

Here, `visitMethod` is overridden to intercept when encountering the `main` method to modify it and `visitEnd` is overridden to append the entirely new `showTwo` method. The `MainTransformer` will intercept `RETURN` instructions (there should be only one in your example) to insert the call to `showTwo` before it.

```
import org.objectweb.asm.*;
import org.objectweb.asm.commons.GeneratorAdapter;

public class MyTransformer extends ClassVisitor {

  public static byte[] transform(byte[] b) {
    final ClassReader classReader = new ClassReader(b);
    final ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(classReader,
      ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES|ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS);
    classReader.accept(new MyTransformer(cw), ClassReader.EXPAND_FRAMES);
    return cw.toByteArray();
  }

  public MyTransformer(ClassVisitor cv) {
    super(Opcodes.ASM5, cv);
  }
  @Override
  public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc,
      String signature, String[] exceptions) {

    MethodVisitor v=super.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions);
    if(name.equals("main") && desc.equals("([Ljava/lang/String;)V"))
      v=new MainTransformer(v, access, name, desc, signature, exceptions);
    return v;
  }
  @Override
  public void visitEnd() {
    appendShowTwo();
    super.visitEnd();
  }
  private void appendShowTwo() {
    final MethodVisitor defVisitor = super.visitMethod(
      Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC, "showTwo", "()V", null, null);
    defVisitor.visitCode();
    defVisitor.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETSTATIC,
      "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
    defVisitor.visitLdcInsn("Show Two Method");
    defVisitor.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL,
      "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", false);
    defVisitor.visitInsn(Opcodes.RETURN);
    defVisitor.visitMaxs(0, 0);
    defVisitor.visitEnd();
  }
  class MainTransformer extends GeneratorAdapter
  {
    MainTransformer(MethodVisitor delegate, int access, String name, String desc,
        String signature, String[] exceptions) {
      super(Opcodes.ASM5, delegate, access, name, desc);
    }
    @Override
    public void visitInsn(int opcode) {
      if(opcode==Opcodes.RETURN) {
        // before return insert c.showTwo();
        super.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, 1); // variable c
        super.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL,
            "ClassName", "showTwo", "()V", false);
      }
      super.visitInsn(opcode);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But can please explain the flow of this program. Where is the main method to execute this ASM program. how it ll generate the new class. can u please give the full code sir!!

Comment: There is no `main` method as you didn’t specify in your question what that `main` method should do. I already addressed this in the beginning of my answer. I provided a `static` method accepting a byte array and providing a byte array. Where you get that array from and what you will do with the result, that depends on what you really wanna do. I can’t read your mind.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. what i want to do is: read this class file and perform these changes and generate another class file with these changes made. can u plz help me sir!

Comment: So [reading a file into a byte array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Path)) and [writing a byte array into a file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write(java.nio.file.Path,%20byte[],%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) is no magic. That works for class files like for every other file. At which point do you have difficulties?

Comment: the problem is I dont understand how to combine ClassVisitor ClassReader and ClassWriter. plz explain the flow of it.
can u plz give the code in ASM 4.0??

Comment: The example code shows “how to combine ClassVisitor ClassReader and ClassWriter”. If you need ASM4, just replace `Opcodes.ASM5` with `Opcodes.ASM4` in the example, there are no differences, as far as I know. I don’t know how I should explain “the flow of it”. Do you know [how the visitor pattern works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)?

Comment: I am just a beginer sir. and i dont know much about visitor pattern. I ll work with this and get back to u sir. thanks for ur efforts.

Comment: Hi.. thanks!! I have one more doubt! suppose if i have a statement in a method as "int average=sum()/5;" I need to change that to "int average=20/5;" is that possible?

Comment: Sure. You have to override `visitMethodInsn` and check whether the invoked method is your `"sum"` method. If so, call `super.visitLdcInsn(20);` in order to replace it, call super.visitMethodInsn` otherwise.

Comment: Sir!! can u please specify the code to replace a function call. Am not getting which method to call and override. It ll b of grt help sir!

Comment: @Narayana: the comments are not meant to ask dozens of new questions. If you have a new question, [open a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).