# Java bytecode asm - Best way to deal with the subclass reference in a class that is being replaced?

Tags: java, java-8, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

I was replacing a class with [SimpleRemapper](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/commons/SimpleRemapper.html) just to change the name of the class. However, I'm running into a problem for a class that has a method which has a reference to the subclass. For an example,

```
public class Target {
  public void func(TargetSubclass other) {
    assert (other.isInstanceOf[Target]) 
  }
}
```

After `Target` class becomes `ClonedTarget`, it fails as `TargetSubclass` class is NOT a child of `ClonedTarget`.

What would be the best way to handle this issue?

I was thinking about dynamically detecting such class and creating a clone of that which extends the clone of the current class (`ClonedTargetSubclass extends ClonedTarget`). But I realised this could become complicated if `TargetSubclass` is not a direct child of `Target` and rather a great child and etc.

Comment: Cloning the entire class hierarchy is the only reliable way. All other solutions would be limited to certain use cases (and we know nothing about yours). by the way, `(other.isInstanceOf[Target])` is supposed to mean `other instanceof Target;`?